# Javascript Namespace declarations in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, namespaces

If you're declaring namespaces in ASP.NET webforms, is it better to just use `Type.registerNamespace` or the usual way of `var $Namespace = function() {
}`

Comment: Is this really related to ASP.Net?

Comment: I dunno. That's what I'm working on right now. Is Type not restricted to ASP.NET?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's an MS AJAX thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a blog post describing `Type.registerNamespace`: http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/bmains/archive/2009/05/30/ajax-and-type-registernamespace-how-it-works.aspx
Basically the two methods are the same thing.
If you're using MS AJAX then go with `Type.registerNamespace`, otherwise stick to plain ol' JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `Type.registerNamespace(...)` because it already handles creating sub-namespaces for you and won't overwrite existing namespaces.

Suppose you want to declare a namespace "A.B.C". Then you're talking about the difference between writing:

```
if(typeof A === "undefined") { A = function() { }; }
if(typeof A.B === "undefined") { A.B = function() { }; }
if(typeof A.B.C === "undefined") { A.B.C = function() { }; }
```

and:

```
Type.registerNamespace("A.B.C");
```

Obviously the latter is a time-saver and easier to read after the fact.